# OS X Terminal using default ANSI colours for every theme

Tags: macos, terminal, osx-lion, colors

For some reason, every theme I palette I've had installed for the OS X Terminal.app has reverted to using the default ANSI colours. The themes have been working fine up until this point and I can't seem to determine what could have caused them to revert in this way. For reference, my standard Solarized Dark colour scheme should look like this …

[image]

… but it currently looks like this:

[image]

A quick look in the preferences panel shows that all the colours are correct save for the ANSI colours which have reverted to their defaults.

I don't know what other information would be helpful but if you need any other info to help me troubleshoot just ask and I'll update as quickly as I can.

Answer (score 0):

Bizzarely enough, the problem seems to have resolved itself without any need for restarts or anything, so I'm closing this thread.